# What are Reserved Data Types in OpenCL?

Tags: c, opencl

I want to write a kernel that takes a float3 data type and returns a bool4 data type. I looked into the specification, bool*n* is not listed under the **Built-in Vector Data Types** like the float*n*, rather it is listed under **Reserved Data Types**, so I tried to use it like this:

```
( __global const float3 *vectors , __global bool4 *booleans)
```

But it returns an error `Unknown type name 'bool4'`. So what are Reserved Data Types and how can I use them?

Comment: Google, first result: they [cannot be used by applications as user-defined type names.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/reservedDataTypes.html)

Comment: I read that, but I still don't understand.why are they written in the specification if they can't be used? and what is the alternative for using a bool4?

Comment: `bool4` is not reserved. Seems like `typen` is reserved if n is not a power of two. So float3 is reserved, but you could simply use a float4.

Comment: You mean use a float4 instead of a bool4? That would be super inefficient since I will be copying it to the host memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reserved data types [cannot be used by applications as user-defined type names](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/reservedDataTypes.html).

- `float3` is reserved, as well as `floatn`, with n not being a power of 2. So I would recommand using `float4` and to not matter about the last component
- `bool4` is reserved, as well as `booln` for all n. You can still use a `char4` though.

If size in memory really matters, you can use the following:

```
union {
    char raw;
    struct st {
        unsigned int i : 1; // bit field to use only one bit
    } c[4];
} my_bool4;
```

And then access each component with `my_bool4.c[i]` for all i in [0,3], or with `my_bool4.raw` and bit masks.

This way, `my_bool4` will only be 1 byte long instead of 4 bytes long for `char4` (well, it depends on compilers, but you *asked* for 1 byte).